# Can I access the collection an instance method was called on in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reflection, activerecord

I'm working on implementing a search form in a ruby on rails application. The general idea is to use form_tag to submit the search fields (via params) to a search function in the model of the class I'm trying to search. The search function will then iterate through each of the params and execute a scoping function if the name of the function appears in params.

The issue is that when I call the search on a collection like so:

```
@calendar.reservations.search({:search_email => "test"})
```

I don't know how to refer to the collection of @calendar.reservations from within the search function.

Additionally I'm confused as to why @calendar.reservations.search(...) works, but Reservations.all.search gives me an error saying you can't call an instance method on an array.

I've got the details of the search method over here: https://gist.github.com/783964

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't know how to refer to the
>   collection of @calendar.reservations
>   from within the search function.

If you use `self` (or `Reservation`, it's the same object) inside the classmethod, you will access the records with the current scope, so in your case you will see only the reservations of a particular calendar.

[edit] I looked at you search function, and I think what you want is:

```
def self.search(search_fields)  
  search_fields.inject(self) do |scope, (key, value)|
    scope.send(key, value)
  end
end
```

> Additionally I'm confused as to why
>   @calendar.reservations.search(...)
>   works, but Reservations.all.search
>   gives me an error saying you can't
>   call an instance method on an array.

`@calendar.reservations` does not return a standard array but a (lazy) [AssociationCollection](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html),  where you can still apply scopes (and classmethods as your `filter`). On the other hand `Reservation.all` returns a plain array, so you cannot execute `search` there (or any scope, for that matter).

Comment: I didn't try Reservation, but self returns the Reservation Class.

Comment: @biagidp, yes, of course it returns the Reservation class, but try to do something with it (for example self.count, it will gave you the same output than @calendar.reservations.count; or self.all, it will give you the array)

Comment: @biagidp: I updadet the answer, look and the refactor of the search method. This should work unless you are using a very old Rails version (probably < 2.3.4)

Comment: tokland: thanks for answering my question so thoroughly and keeping at it to help me learn something today!

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need a `search` method at all, as far as I can tell.

Simply use `where`:

```
@calendar.reservations.where(:search_email => 'test')
```

Comment: Well, maybe *search* is doing some more work we don't see. It's not bad to have a separate method for the task (there you can make *where*s and whatever you need to; maybe transform values, save searches, etc)

Comment: It doesn't seem so according to his Gist: https://gist.github.com/783964  But good point, anyway.

Comment: The search function is for iterating over multiple key, value pairs and applying each to as-yet unwritten scoping methods. The end result I'm after is dynamic scoping based on form input.

Comment: @biagidp, you can apply multiple scopes with inject.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly encourage you to look at the [MetaSearch](http://metautonomo.us/projects/metasearch/) GEM by Ernie Miller. It handles the kind of thing you're working on very elegantly and is quite easy to implement. I suspect that your view code would almost accomplish what the GEM needs already, and this would take care of all your model searching needs very nicely.

Take a look and see if it will solve your problem. Good luck!

Comment: This all started because searchlogic wont work with rails 3. MetaSearch looks like an awesome replacement. I'll definitely give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

`Reservation.all.search` doesn't work because it returns all the results as an array, while `Reservation.where(..)` returns an ActiveRecord object (AREL). Reservation.all actually fetches the results instead of just building the query further, which methods like `where`, `limit` etc do.